# ls and regular expression linux

Tags: regex, linux, ls

I have two directories:

1. `run.2016-02-25_01.`
2. `run.2016-02-25_01.47.04`

Both these directories are present under a common directory called `gte`.

I want a directory that ends without a dot character `.`.

I am using the following command, however, I am not able to make it work:

```
ls run* | grep '.*\d+'
```

The commands is not able to find anything.

Comment: I'm not sure your regex will do what you want, so you may want to double-check it afterwards, but your immediate problem is that you should pass the `-d` option to `ls`. Otherwise, it will list the directories' content, not the directories themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The negated character set in shell globbing uses `!` not `^`:

```
ls -d run*[!.]
```

(The `^` was at one time an archaic synonym for `|`.)  The `-d` option lists directory names, not the contents of those directories.

---

Your attempt using:

```
ls run* | grep '.*\d+'
```

requires a PCRE-enabled `grep` and the PCRE regex option (`-P`), and you are looking for zero or more of any character followed by one or more digits, which isn't what you said you wanted.  You could use:

```
ls -d run* | grep '[^.]$'
```

which doesn't require the PCRE regexes, but simply having the shell glob the right names is probably best.

If you're worried that there might not be a name starting `run` and ending with something other than a dot, you should consider `shopt -s nullglob`, as mentioned in [Anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35634469/15168).  However, note the discussion below between [hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl) and myself about the potentially confusing behaviour of, in particular, the `ls` command in conjunction with `shopt -s nullglob`.  If you were using:

```
for name in run*[!.]
do
    …
done
```

then `shopt -s nullglob` is perfect; the loop iterates zero times when there's no match for the glob expression.  It isn't so good when the glob expression is an argument to commands such as `ls` that provide a default behaviour in the absence of command line arguments.

Comment: @hek2mgl: Really?  It works for me with Bash 3.2.  `>xx1; >xx2; >xx.; ls xx[!.]` only lists `xx1` and `xx2` (assuming there were no other 3-character files starting `xx` in the directory).  Also in Korn shell.

Comment: Thanks!! Exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Uh, it seems to be a problem with my test setup but still interesting: I've created the files `test-232` and `test-232.` (Note the `-` instead of the `.`). However, when I use `ls test.*[!.]` I get `test-232` and `test-232.`. I wouldn't expected that. Am I missing something?

Comment: Uh! Again my test setup! I had `shopt -s nullglob` because of the discussion with anubhava below. I'm entirely not a glob master! :) I would not expected that result because `nullglob`. I would expected an empty result in my test.

Comment: _Typed and checked before seeing the "Uh! Again…" comment._  I'm not sure what's going on for you.  I tried: `>test-232; >test-232.; ls test.*[!.]` and get 'cannot access test.*[!.]: No such file or directory' from `ls`.  Running `ls test*[!.]` shows just `test-232` and not the dot-suffixed file.  I'm using `LANG=en_US.UTF8` for locale; I don't know if that's a factor in the problem — it is about all I can think of.  The `.*` vs `*` is puzzling indeed.  I'll play with `shopt -s nullglob` shortly.

Comment: Oh…of course…!  (Once spotted, it's obvious; until then, it's mystifying.)  The `shopt -s nullglob` means that the `test.*[!.]` expands to nothing, so `ls` lists the contents of the current directory, which might only contain the file names we're looking at if it was created for testing.  It was more obvious to me — I was playing in an ordinary working directory so I got a lot of files listed.  This is the sort of reason why `shopt -s nullglob` is not the default, I expect.

Answer (score 1):

This works...

```
ls|grep '.*[^.]$'
```

That is saying I want any amount of anything but I want the last character before the line ending to be anything except for a period.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `grep`. Just use:

```
shopt -s nullglob
ls -d run*[0-9]
```

If your directories are not always ending with digits then use `extglob`:

```
shopt -s nullglob extglob
ls -d run*+([^.])
```

or to list all entries inside the `run*` directory ending without DOT:

```
printf "%s\n" run*+([^.])/*
```

Comment: OP wants the folders *without* a dot

Comment: Yes sorry I interpreted opposite. It is fixed now

Comment: Ok. Propably `shopt -s nullglob` should be set, since if no such a folder exists, the current code will give you (literally) `run*[0-9]/*`

Comment: Ok, works for me. The `/*` trick to ensure it is a) a directory and b) not ending with a dot is nice! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `find`

```
find -regextype posix-awk -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '-*[[:digit:]]+$'
```

Answer (score 0):

To list the directories that don't end with a `.` .

`ls -d run* |grep "[^.]$"`

Comment: No need to escape the period with the slash since period has no special meaning inside square brackets.